# libgdx - gameoverscreen won't show

Tags: java, android, libgdx

//this is my script where i am calling the gameoverscreen. i want it to set to this screen when my sprite overlaps another sprite.

```
if (grumpface.whiteballoon.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(spriterect)) {
            System.out.println("hey");
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameOverScreen());
        };
```

then here is the class i am setting the screen too . its giving me an error where the stage is drawn, which makes me think the show() method is not firing creating the stage.

```
class GameOverScreen implements Screen{

    private Stage stage;

    // Called automatically once for init objects
    @Override
    public void show() { 

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        stage.setDebugAll(true); // Set outlines for Stage elements for easy debug

        BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("hazey.fnt"), false);
        LabelStyle headingStyle = new LabelStyle(white, Color.WHITE);
        Label gameoverstring = new Label("game ovaaaa!", headingStyle);
        gameoverstring.setPosition(100, 100);
        stage.addActor(gameoverstring);

    }

    // Called every frame so try to put no object creation in it
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) { 
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
```

here is the stack trace error whenever the overlap happens.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mygdx.game.GameOverScreen.render(GameOverScreen.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:139)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:214)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationrun(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are creating a variable called `stage` in your `show()` method but you should use the class variable.

It should look like this: `stage = new Stage();`.

Cause when you assign the `Stage stage = new Stage();` in your show it will write it in the local variable `stage` and not in the class variable. So the even created `Stage` is garbage after the `show();` method was called. So when you are entering the `render(float delta);` method the `stage` class variable is `null` and the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a local variable named stage in show() method, and the global variable named stage has not initialized yet thats why you are getting an exception named null pointer exception. Initialize your global stage in show() method rather than creating a new local variable.

```
public void show()
{
 stage= new Stage();
}
```

if you are confused between local and global variable then have a look at this link given below:

http://www.amitranjanji.com/2012/05/differentiate-between-global-local.html